# How is a statistic represented as a mapping with varying number of arguments?

Tags: statistics, elementary-set-theory

Suppose that are $n$  sample points taking values in $A$.

A statistic for sample size $n$ is a mapping from $A^n$ to another set $B$.

But $n$ can vary in $\mathbb N$. There are also similarities among the mappings with different $n$. How would you represent a mapping with varying number of arguments then? I am open to solutions or suggestions from both set theory and statistics.

Thanks and regards!

Comment: You could simply take $A^{\lt\omega}=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A^n$ to be your domain if you want a single function to work for all possible sizes of input.